# JQuery - datepicker doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am new in JQuery and I need to use datepicker to get date in form. I am using this code:

HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(function() {
     $( "#date" ).focus().datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="date"></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

But when I click on field, nothing happen. When I tried to use this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="datepicker"></div>

<script>
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It is working... Thanks for tips.

Additionally: I am using Nette framework, where I can inherit templates... Could this be the problem?

Comment: What does the console say? (F12 -> Console)

Comment: As an aside, unless you're forced to (you have no control over the web server), it's not good practice to use `<meta>` tags to set the character set. It forces a reload/parse of the document by the browser upon reading.

Comment: why you use focus() ?

Comment: @Phylogenesis - And thats why MDN [recommends the meta charset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Obsolete_things_to_avoid) tag, because it's bad and should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: @adeneo Not really. It just recommends against using the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` tag. A better way is to actually use HTTP headers to do the same thing, but this requires access to the web server configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just focus it after you've initialized the datepicker, otherwise the input is focused before there is a datepicker attached.

```
$( "#date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).focus();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Fw72/)

Comment: I don't think you need `.focus()` for input element, it is also working without `.focus()`.  `$( "#date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });`

Comment: @jogesh_pi - I assumed the focus was there to focus the element and make the datepicker visible on pageload.

Comment: Tho FOCUS was added in last second. Anyway it still doesn't work. I don't understand why. In fiddle it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing with the option like this:

```
$('#date').datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'dd-mm-yy' ).datepicker();
```

Comment: @AnoopJoshi - Of course he didn't. This sets the options for an existing datepicker, it does not create a new one.